# get pixel color when image view ' s width is set match_parent when image view contain small image

Tags: java, android

Hi I want to get pixel color when i touch image view , this code is working fine when width and height of image view in xml is wrap content

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_cam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

, problem arises when in xml file i set width and height of image view wrap content to  match parent

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_cam"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

by doing this small images become stretch
error comes 
E/MessageQueue-JNI(1006): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width()

how can i solve this ...

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

```
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){           

    ImageView iv = ((ImageView)v);      
    Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    int pixel = bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());// error comes in this line
    int alphaValue = Color.alpha(pixel);
    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

    Toast.makeText(this,"[" +alphaValue+"," +redValue+","+greenValue+","+blueValue+"]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the dimensions of your bitmap against the bitmap itself.

```
if ((bmp.getHeight() < (int)event.getY() || (bmp.getWidth() < (int)event.getX() ) {
// not within range
}
```

Comment: no this is not exactly what i want , i can handle error by wrap_content, but i want imageview to fit the screen , and i think bmp.getHeight() will return the original height , not after stretching so do u have any other suggestion.... and by the way thanks for reply

Comment: Have you tried iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY) or any other scales?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but it might still be relevant. As far as I can tell, the Bitmap references different pixels than the ones you get with getPixel() of the event. What I did is offset these pixels as follows:

```
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;        
    int [] imgCenter = new int[2];
    img.getLocationOnScreen(imgCenter);
    int x = evX - imgCenter[0];  // These are your desired coordinates
    int y = evY - imgCenter[1];  // evX & evY are the event's coordinates
```